# I'd like users to see everyone else who is currently logged into my site

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm writing a fairly complex project management system using Javascript, PHP and mySQL. All users are stored in a mySQL table and when they log in I set a session variable in PHP and log the last time that they logged in. I do this simply so people can't increase their number of visits by hitting F5.

I would like all users who are logged in to be able to see a list of all other users currently logged in to the site.

The only way I can see to solve this would be to fire a PHP script (say every 10 seconds) which would do 2 things. Log the current time of the current user into the mySQL table then look at the last log times all the other users. Anyone with a last log time of less than say 20 seconds before the current time would be shown as logged in.

I know how to do all of this using timers in Javascript, Ajax etc. but it just seems to me a rather inelegant way of accomplishing what I need.

My questions:

Is this the best way of achieving what I want

Is it good programming practice to send ajax calls and update mySQL databases as frequently as every 10 seconds for every user.

Comment: A loggedin scheme just like the one I proposed can be found in this excellent book (Core Web Application Development with PHP and MySQL) and it will help you a lot I think.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just checked out the book on Amazon - looks to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Not sure why my question was closed and marked down. seems to me I had 2 distinct questions and going on the response I've had answers - ah well

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a table say "loggedinusers" that has information about the users that are logged in currently. Now you will definitely use javascipt if you want to refresh the list on the page and that will have to be done with Ajax querying with a timer the db.

Another solution would be to have a php module on the page that will queries the db when you navigate to each page. So you will get info about new users logged in while the user navigates through your site. This is quite reasonable I guess.

Performance will not be hit from a small table (just a few thousand entries).

Comment: "queries the db when you navigate to each page" - this is performance killer

Comment: The assumption is that this is not a huge table of millions of logged in users.

Comment: My app does a lot of db querying via PHP and I did consider updating the logged in list every time the db was queried. But ideally I'd like a more accurate system just in case a user is logged in but not doing anything that queries the db. It's more of an app than a website so it's all on one page with javascript handling all navigation

Comment: When a user logs in the system his userid ends up in a loggedintable. Unless he logs out he is there. You don't need to wait for him to query anything.

Comment: If the user just closes their browser and don't click a logout button, how do I know they've logged out? At what point are they removed from the loggedintable?

Comment: Well you can remove stale logins with several ways. For example you set a 50/50 chance whenever you query the table that you will remove users loggedin an not updated the loggedin table for more than 1 hour (supposedly you have 1 hour expiration in your cookie)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Whichever way I look at this, I am still going to have to retreive a list of active users into my javascript program to be able to display them. I was hoping I could avoid regularly calling scripts but the more I think about it, I'll have to other there is no way my program will know who is logged on. Appreciate your help and have upvoted both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the architecture.

If this information will be available only for you and some group of extra users - you may just grep Varnish / Apache / Nginx logs (you can add some extra logging to show cookies and so) every 1 - 2 minutes  and output it to the static html page - which will be available after providing credentials.

It is bit different way to do it - but does not affect performance of your platform.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into your idea. Is it such a performance killer if I'm sending ajax calls and querying the db every 10 seconds. If it's done Asynchronously would the user even notice?

Comment: Is your idea something along the lines of setting a unique session cookie for each user from PHP? If so, how do I retreive all these session cookies?

Comment: Changing the logging configuration. For example you can do it in varnishncsa:
 %{Cookie}i, for apache you have for example:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_usertrack.html

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Whichever way I look at this, I am still going to have to retreive a list of active users into my javascript program to be able to display them. I was hoping I could avoid regularly calling scripts but the more I think about it, I'll have to other there is no way my program will know who is logged on. Appreciate your help and have upvoted both of you.